# Win_ros fuerte broadcasting messages to linux machine

Tags: ros, linux, windows, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just installed win_ros fuerte.  I have been running electric on windows without any problems.  A linux box acts as the Master and the windows machine broadcasts messages to the linux box.  However, with win_ros fuerte I am unable to get my messages across to the linux box.  Win_ros will run fine with the ROS_MASTER_URI set to the ip address of the linux machine.  Also, when I start broadcasting messages from windows I can see the message name when I type "rostopic list" on both the windows and the linux sides.  However, I can only echo the messages on the windows side.  It seems like there is enough connectivity between the machines to see that a message started, but not enough to actually pass the data.  The same thing happens when windows is the "master".  Ros_wtf just gives an unknown network error.

I realize this is a vague question -- I'm mainly interested in knowing if anyone has successfully talked between windows and linux with win_ros fuerte.

Thanks!
Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37103/win_ros-fuerte-broadcasting-messages-to-linux-machine/) by [MarkC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2696/markc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like it is the usual multi-machine problem. If so, it's not directly related to winros, just make sure you get your ip/hostname settings exported correctly.

Seing as this question comes up often with windows-linux ros connections, I've added some information on the [WinRoS FAQ](http://ros.org/wiki/win_ros/faq). A direct link to the issue in detail is  [here](http://ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Resolving%20One%20Way%20Broadcasting%20Issues).

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can confirm that I've successfully sent data from a windows computer to Linux using fuerte. I followed the instructions for setting up the SDK on Windows 7 and then built a ROS node using Visual Studio. I was able to send both data and video to a Linux computer over the network (with roscore running on the Linux box). Other than changing ROS_MASTER_URI, the only other thing I can remember that I did was to add entries to the hosts file on both the Windows and Linux computers (to make sure each computer had the correct IP address of the other).

---

Originally posted by [Jon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1247/jon/) with karma: 115 on 2012-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2